# Unable to cd to directory which I own with permissions 777

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, ubuntu-10.10

This is on a customized Ubuntu 10.10 LiveCD. I have a directory which the default user "ubuntu" owns, and the permissions on the directory is 777. I'm unable to cd into the directory as ubuntu user. However as root user I'm able to access it. What could be the reason? I'm able to view the directory in nautilus.
Note: I originally copied the folder over from an NTFS disk.

Comment: What is the error message when you try to `cd` into the directory? What does `ls -ld /path/to/directory` show? If there's a `+` at the end of the first column, what does `getfacl /path/to/directory` show? (If there's a `+`, it means there's an ACL, and that's probably the culprit.)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I rebuilt the LiveCD and it automatically started working. Not sure what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give the output of

```
ls -la /your/directory
```

and

```
groups ubuntu
```

?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I rebuilt the LiveCD and it automatically started working. Not sure what was wrong.